# getting the sizes of product in the cart

Tags: javascript

i have this code :

```
 if (action=="add"){
           if(cart[productId]==undefined ){
               cart[productId]={'quantity':1}
               cart[productId]['size']=size
           }
            if (cart[productId]['size'] in array1){
                  cart[productId]['quantity']+=1
                  cart[productId]['size']=size
            }
            else{
                  console.log('the products '+cart.length+' '+cart[productId]["size"])
                  cart[productId]={'quantity':1}
                  cart[productId]['size']=size
                }
    }
```

this is an example of a cart

```json
{
    '1': { 'quantity': 1, 'size': 'XL' },
    '3': { 'quantity': 3, 'size': 'L' }
}
```

and i want to make an array of all the sizes of an specific product in the array1

Comment: what is the issue and what is expected output could you explain a bit more ?

Comment: [How to reference & loop through JSON object properties](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_json_objects.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Hope the following code will help you.

```
var cart = {
    '1': { 'quantity': 1, 'size': 'XL' },
    '3': { 'quantity': 3, 'size': 'L' }
}, newCart=[];
newCart = Object.keys(cart).map((v)=>{
  return cart[v].size;
});
console.log(newCart);
```